# How to modify Url after getCurrentUrl() in protractor test?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have been struggling with these lines of protractor test today.

```
element(by.linkText('text')).click();
var url = browser.getCurrentUrl();
url = url + '-new';
browser.get(url);
```

I want to get the current url from the browser, modify it (by adding '-new' at the end) and go to this new browser window for the rest of my tests.

I am getting an external protocol request from chrome while running my tests and if I click on allow the test just ends abruptly.

Comment: did you try browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url){
url = url + '-new';
browser.get(url);
}); I am thinking your url is an unresolved promise when you are trying to concatenate on to it.

Answer (score 0):

browser.getCurrentUrl() returns a promise.
The following code worked for me in the end.

```
var url_promise = browser.getCurrentUrl();
return url_promise.then(function (url) {
    var new_url = url+'-new';
    return browser.get(new_starting_bids_url);
});
```